# .Body will not compile but quote and new line brackets seem correct

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am playing with a script that sends emails from an excel sheet. the body of my email is not compiling. However I have wrapped everything in "" with & _ breaks for when it goes too far and `.value _ & vbNewLine & _` for line breaks

I have tried annotating out chunks of the email body to fish out the syntax error

```
.Body = "Hello " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
        & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "this is Paul from the XYZ and I just left you a voicemail message for you. " & _
        "We are reaching out to you because you’ve been identified in the XYZ system as someone who manages XYZ " & _
        "The XYZ form, which you have been using, will be retired after XYZ and be replaced with a new process and system. " & _
        "If you onboard XYZ for your organization, this means you will be directly impacted. " & _
        "We need to collect your information to set you up in our new system and ensure there is no interruption moving forwards. " & _
        "We will reach out again and if you can please provide the following information below: ".Value _
         & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
         "Best email to contact you: ".Value _
         & vbNewLine & _
         "Best phone number to reach you: ".Value _
         & vbNewLine & _
         "Best time of day to schedule our next call: ".Value _
         & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
         "If you have any questions or concerns, please don’t hesitate to reach out directly to me at XYZ ".Value _
         & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
         "Thank you, "
```

Email should go out. But instead I get a syntax error compile error

Comment: I have no MS-Office here to test but methinks it should always be `& _\n`, not `_\n&` like you have in several places

Comment: @Holli that makes no difference. As long as the underscore is preceded by a space, where the concatenation operator goes is a matter of personal preference. The inconsistency makes it annoyingly hard to find where the bug is though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> "Best email to contact you: ".Value _
> ```

There's the error. That `.Value` member call is illegal, a string literal doesn't have members. You probably mean to be doing this:

```
"Best email to contact you: " & .Value _
```

Same here:

> ```
> "Best phone number to reach you: ".Value _
> ```

And here:

> ```
> "Best time of day to schedule our next call: ".Value _
> ```

And here too:

> ```
> "We will reach out again and if you can please provide the following information below: ".Value _
> ```

Now, the inconsistency of whether you put the `&` at the end or at the start of a line, makes the code extremely hard to parse. Decide whether you want it at the end or at the beginning, and stick to it.

Comment: Thank you this helped me figure it out!